# TFS and various solution and their outputs

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am using TFS and vS2017 for the projects.
I have various around 5 projects in the TFS. I want to package all the 5 solution outputs onto the one folder(latest). And once generated, i want to package them using windows installer/install shield.
The final folder which contains the output of all 5 solution should also be checked in the TFS.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: TFS Automated Build and deploy services is one solution to this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff650529.aspx

Comment: Are these 5 solutions in the same team project of TFS? Are you working with the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)?

Answer (score 2):

If these 5 solutions are in the same team project of TFS. You could create a single build definition to handle this situation.

> Use the **wildcard** solution to find all solutions `**/*.sln` will
>   build all solutions in the  repository/workspace.
>
> - You can use a workspace cloaking rule if you're using TFVC for source    control to exclude one of your solution files from the
>     workspace,    that way it won't be downloaded from sourcecontrol and
>     won't be    built. (If you have more than five solutions in the
>     workspace)

You could also add multiples [Visual Studio Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build) tasks in on build definition (mainly used for controling the order that they get built.)

Then invoke Visual Studio to create the setup package  follow below steps:

- Add a step and select the “Command Line” task from the Utility
  section.
- Enter the path to devenv.com for the Tool parameter (this is
  typically “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com”).
- The arguments have the following format: *solutionPath /build
  configuration projectPath*

  1. solutionPath is the path to the solution file
  2. configuration is the config (debug, release etc.)
  3. projectPath is the path to the vdproj file

More details please refer this blog: [Building VS 2015 Setup Projects in Team Build](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build)

[Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) add [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts)  to publish build artifacts to TFS or a file share, finally use a powershell script to check in TFS.

Comment: Thanks, yes all the 5 solution is in the TFS - team project. I will try out.